# JSP: Same code and same input, but different output? UTF-8 BOM issue

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8

At first let me show the code:

Java class:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Reader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        show("test.txt");
    }

    public static void show(String fileName) {
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            while (reader.ready())
                data.append(reader.readLine()).append("\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(data);
        for (int i=0; i<data.length(); i++)
            System.out.println(data.codePointAt(i));
    }
}
```

JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import = "test.*" %>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<% Reader.show("test.txt"); %>
</body>
</html>
```

The test file **test.txt** is in `UTF-8 with BOM` encoding with four visible characters: "TEST". You can create yourself or download [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B780bzuCDXSNNC1NbXNtRkt3bzQ/view?usp=sharing).

The Reader class simply shows the content and the code point of each character of the file.
That is, it is supposed to print `TEST` and the code points `65279 84 69 83 84 10` where `65279` is the BOM character and `10` is the new line character.

However, I execute the same code in JSP and the output is `嚜燜EST` with the code points `22172 29148 69 83 84 10`. It's weird and I can't figure out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be a charset problem, add this line of code to the beginning of `show()`: `System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().name());`. Run the Reader class and the JSP page to check if there is any difference.

**Updated**:
I have downloaded your `test.txt` file and tested your code under Mac OS X with JDK 1.8.0_45, Tomcat 8.0.32, both give the same output.